# Path from .rtf file to RichTextBox

Tags: c#, activereports

I have problem with RichTextBox in C#.

When I try load to RichTextBox text like "C:\Users\adasal\Desktop\raporty_handel\rpt\rtf\bruegman.rtf" from .rtf file I gettingn something like "C:_handel.rtf"

This code is write in Active Reports console.

My code:

```
string resoult = "C:\\Users\\adasal\\Desktop\\raporty_handel\\rpt\\rtf\\bruegman.rtf"     
System.IO.FileStream rtfCreate = System.IO.File.Create(resoult);
System.Byte[] info = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(resoult);
rtfCreate.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
rtfCreate.Close();

System.IO.FileStream streamRTF = new System.IO.FileStream(resoult, 
System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);    
this.RichTextBox1.Load(streamRTF, RichTextType.Rtf);
```

Someone can help? I want to show whole path on report.

Comment: Your current example doesn't make much sense to me, can you please try to explain what exactly you're trying to do? To me it currently looks like you are writing the filename (`resoult`) into a new file at the location specified by `resoult`. Since the contents of `resoult` is not valid RTF the `RichTextBox` will only display the broken text you're seeing. You need to create a valid RTF file in order for the `RichTextBox` to be able to load it properly.

Comment: I want to create a .rtf file and insert into it text path that leads to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape '\' characters which have special meaning in RTF.
For example:

```
public void ActiveReport_ReportStart()
{
    string resoult = "C:\\Users\\adasal\\Desktop\\raporty_handel\\rpt\\rtf\\bruegman.rtf";
    this.RichTextBox1.RTF = resoult.Replace("\\", "\\\\"); 
}
```

Comment: you could just replace "\\" by "/", e.g. string resoult = "C:/Users/rpt/rtf/bruegman.rtf"